# MS Word: How to supress list numbers from Table of Contents

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, table-of-contents

I would like to make a TOC automatically in MS Word 2010/2016. I do not want the numbered for the multilevel list to appear in the TOC text.

I have formatted by headings and subheadings using Heading 1 and Heading 2 styles. I've also formatted each list level using List 1 and List 2.

In Word's TOC options I have set it up such that Heading 1-3 corresponds to TOC level 1-3 and List 1-2 corresponds to TOC Level 4-5.

The Text it was generated from
[image: Body Text]

The TOC generated:

[image: The TOC generated:]

The TOC I want (Notice that the auto numbering from the list is gone):
[image: The TOC I want]

Answer (score 0):

You can use field codes to generate the TOC. Actually, from your first image, it appears that your heading 1s ('Animals' and 'Things') are already correct, so you can save some manual steps and use a combination of field codes (for levels 2–5) and styles/outline levels (for level 1).

First, add `TC` fields to the various headings and list items that should appear in the TOC.

1. Place the cursor at the beginning or end of the '1. Mammals' paragraph, or even select the whole paragraph, and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (that's the letter O, not a zero).
2. In the **Entry** field, enter the text that should appear in the TOC (if you selected the whole paragraph in step 1, the paragraph text will be automatically entered for you).
3. Set **Level** to **2**, because you want the '1. Mammals' heading to be a 2nd-level entry.
4. Click **Mark**.
5. Repeat steps 1–4 for everything that you want to be a level-2, level-3, level-4, or level-5 heading, setting the **Level** field as appropriate.

(You can also insert the `TC` fields as you'd insert other fields – e.g., from the **Insert** tab. There will be field options for setting the entry text and level, as you did in the dialog box.)

Next, generate a custom TOC.

1. On the **References** tab, click **Table of Contents** > **Custom Table of Contents**.
2. Set **Show levels** to **5**, because you want your TOC to be 5 levels deep. Set the other options on this main screen to define the appearance of the TOC as you want.
3. Click **Options**.
4. The **Styles** and **Outline levels** check boxes will be selected. Select **Table entry fields** too.
5. In the list under **Available styles**, scroll down and clear the number out of every field except the field for **Heading 1**; leave that set to **1**.
6. Click **OK** twice to insert the TOC.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this out and it work. Is there a way to easily automate this? The reason I have formatted all my headers with styles and generated the TOC from styles is because I work in an environment where changes happen almost daily, thus the number of heading changes and the TOC level could potentially change too, depending on decisions made.

Comment: It could probably be automated with VBA (find every paragraph that needs a TC field, copy the paragraph text, and then insert a field that uses the copied text as the Entry value and has an appropriate Level value, based on the paragraph style); unfortunately, I'm not skilled at coding, so I can't help with that part.